# jQuery Draggable Droppable Pass IDs to Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, draggable, droppable

I am trying to use jquery draggable/droppable to allow me to drag an item to a location and have it pass the id of the item AND the id of the location via ajax to a php file.

In summary if I have 10 items and 2 drag locations, I am hoping that if I dragged an item it would return something like item7 and location2.

Hope this makes sense, this is what I have so far, pretty basic but this only returns the item value, obviously because I think the location variable is unavailable (which I tried to fix unsuccessfully).

```
<script>
  $(function() {
   var location;
$("#draggable" ).draggable({
     revert: "valid",
     drag: function (event, ui) {
         var location = $(this).attr("id");
     }
    });
$(".droppable" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var item = $(this).attr("id");

        $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
            alert(item + location);
    }
});
```

});

As reminder I would like to add ajax to this if possible once I can retrieve both values so I can work it in the database.

Comment: AJAX means a request to the server + a response from the server. It is done via HTTP. You can attach to the request any data you need and you can manipulate the response the way you need. Since you are using jQuery, the answer is here:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, thats awesome but I can't get both variables to populate so even if I figure out the ajax part I would only be passing half of the answer... any help on getting var location to pass to the droppable function along with the currently working var item variable??

Comment: I am not an expert but I feel calling droppable inside the callback of draggable would work(of course triggering the ajax call inside droppable `drop`). I follow this OP to see if there is better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, haven't tested the ajax part of it but the main goal was to retrieve both variables which worked with this

```
<script>
$(".draggable" ).draggable({
     revert: "valid",
     drag: function (event, ui) {   
     }
}); 
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        // This gets the ID of the item you are dragging
        var item_id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        var location = $(this).attr("id");
        $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
            alert(item_id + location);
        // Ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            timeout: 10000,
            url: "item_update.php?item_id="+item_id+"&location="+location,
        });
    }
});
</script>
```